# Core dumped on QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, centos7

I am a new in QT5, and I write a simple QT program in Centos 7, but when I use make, the error message only show "core dumped".

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){

     Bu_fileOpen = new QPushButton("open CSV file", this);
     fileLineEdit =  new QLineEdit(this);
     connect(Bu_fileOpen, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(showfile()));
     qDebug() << "fileLineEdit = " << fileLineEdit <<  endl;

     // ========= check box
     QGroupBox *FE_GroupBox = new QGroupBox("Filter Extraction",this);
     QVBoxLayout *FE_Layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

     check1 = new QCheckBox("FE1",this);
     check2 = new QCheckBox("FE2",this);
     check3 = new QCheckBox("FE3",this);

     FE_Layout->addWidget(check1);
     FE_Layout->addWidget(check2);
     FE_Layout->addWidget(check3);
     FE_GroupBox->setLayout(FE_Layout);

     // =========Radio button
     QGroupBox *AL_GroupBox = new QGroupBox("Aliment",this);
     QVBoxLayout * AL_Layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

     rcheck1 = new QRadioButton("AL1",this);
     rcheck2 = new QRadioButton("AL2",this);
     rcheck3 = new QRadioButton("AL3",this);

     AL_Layout->addWidget(rcheck1);
     AL_Layout->addWidget(rcheck2);
     AL_Layout->addWidget(rcheck3);
     AL_GroupBox->setLayout(AL_Layout);


     // ========= push button to exit
     Bu_Quit = new QPushButton("Quit", this);
     connect(Bu_Quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

     // ========= QVBoxLayout

     QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
     mainLayout->addWidget(Bu_fileOpen,1,0);
     mainLayout->addWidget(fileLineEdit,1,1);

     mainLayout->addWidget(FE_GroupBox,3,0);
     mainLayout->addWidget(AL_GroupBox,2,0);
     mainLayout->addWidget(Bu_Quit,4,0);

     mainLayout->setMargin(10);
     mainLayout->setSpacing(10);
}


void MyWidget::showfile(){

     QFileDialog myFileDialog(this);
     QString fileName = myFileDialog.getOpenFileName(this, "Open File",
               QDir::currentPath (), "CSV Files (*.csv *.xls)");

     if (fileName.isEmpty ()) {
          fileLineEdit->setText (myFileDialog.directory().absolutePath());
     } else {
          fileLineEdit->setText (fileName);
     }
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (i.e. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then **use the debugger**  `gdb` on your executable and the `core`  file

Comment: BTW, your question is not clear enough. Show some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including all your classes.

Comment: You could show the files you are using to compile, if it is cmake, the CMakeLists.txt, if it is qmake you should show the .pro file, or else your makefile.

Comment: Yes, the `-g` for the compiler and try to run it in Valgrind.

Comment: If you're using Qt Creator, switch to a debug build (lower-left corner of Creator, click the monitor icon, select a debug configuration.) Rebuild the project. Then press F5. This will run the program in the debugger. When it crashes, Creator should highlight the code responsible for the crash.

Comment: @NikosC. and give you the stack trace. :)